# How to replace substrings from the substring between the two patterns in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings e.g.

```
$str = '/some-folders/../pattern,replacement-area';

$str = '/some-folders/../pattern,also-replacement-area/parameter-one';
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of `-` to `~` if exists in the replacement area that is between `/pattern,` and  optional `/`

The result must be

```
/some-folders/../pattern,replacement~area

/some-folders/../pattern,also~replacement~area/parameter-one
```

I just know about simple str_replace

```
$str = str_replace("-","~",$str);
```

Please provide efficient code as it will be run many times on a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
(?:/pattern,|(?!^)\G)[^\n/-]*\K-
```

and replace using `~`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4isRJT/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `/pattern,`: Match `/pattern,`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: Start from end of previous match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `[^\n/-]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `/` and `-` and not a line break
- `\K`: reset all the match info
- `-`: Match a `-`

---

**php code:**

```php
$str = '/some-folders/../pattern,also-replacement-area/parameter-one';
$repl = preg_replace('~(?:/pattern,|(?!^)\G)[^\n/-]*\K-~', '~', $str);
echo $repl . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
/some-folders/../pattern,also~replacement~area/parameter-one
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Cheer. In addition RegEx Demo offers a code generator. Just in case, maybe it would be better to add the comma after pattern (?:/pattern,|...

Comment: Good point @Monnomcjo, I missed comma while reading question

Comment: @Syed: I have added php code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Always with the "glue" feature (this time expressed with the A modifier instead of the `\G` escape sequence), but with a different pattern structure that avoids the alternation:

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:^.*?/pattern,)?(?!^)[^/-]*+\K-~A', '~', $str);
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qC8QH/2)
[php demo](https://3v4l.org/2uEL0)

Notice: instead of the possessive quantifier here `[^/-]*+`, you can also use the `(*COMMIT)` backtracking control verb that is interesting to quickly abort the research when there's no dash in the string:

```
~(?:^.*?/pattern,)?(?!^)[^/-]*\K(*COMMIT)-~A
```